# Use Pivot Function to Merge Column sets in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

I have a table in the below format:

```
id colA1 colB1 colA2 colB2
1   100   499   500   999
```

I need it in the below format,

```
id colA colB
1   100  499
1   500  999
```

I tried using `unpivot` method, but it gives as below,

```
 colA  colB
   100  499
   100  999
   500  499
   500  999
```

Query used

```
select * from (select colA, colB from my_table
unpivot
(colA for ColNm1 in(
colA1,
colA2
))
unpivot
(colB for ColNm2 in(
colB1,
colB2
));
```

Comment: I was able to do this using union, but I want it to be implemented using unpivot method.

Comment: ...and for good reason: I believe UNION ALL will mean the base table is read twice, while UNPIVOT reads it just once.

Comment: @mathguy Unpivot has a better performance while executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a single unpivot like so:

```
WITH my_table AS (SELECT 1 ID, 100 cola1, 499 colb1, 500 cola2, 999 colb2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                  SELECT 2 ID, 85 cola1, 163 colb1, 29 cola2, 457 colb2 FROM dual)
select ID,
       cola,
       colb
from   my_table
UNPIVOT ((cola, colb) FOR def_col IN ((cola1, colb1), (cola2, colb2)));

        ID       COLA       COLB
---------- ---------- ----------
         1        100        499
         1        500        999
         2         85        163
         2         29        457
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `UNION ALL`, first select with A1 and B1, second select with A2 and B2:

```
select id, colA1 as colA, colB1 as colB
from my_table
UNION ALL
select id, colA2 as colA, colB2 as colB
from my_table
```

Comment: This was my first reaction too. However, this solution reads the base table twice; I believe UNPIVOT reads it just once, and if so, it should be more efficient.

Comment: @mathguy, maybe you're right, I don't know Oracle very well. However, I'd expect a plain select (or two) without any conditions or order by to be very fast, since it's just a matter of data transfer.

Comment: "Very fast" depends on many factors. For example, what if the data fetching is over a slow network? Pure speculation; but this is why whenever we can read a base table only once vs. twice, it's preferable. (Not knocking your solution - after all, as I said, that was my first reaction too!)

Comment: @mathguy, same amount of data in both cases, so a slow network will be the bottle-neck anyway. Will unpivot need any temporary table?

Comment: OK - let me first state that your solution is perfectly fine. I am only interested in this discussion because I am really curious, want to learn, etc. Not "arguing" with you or anything. Just so it's clear to anyone reading this. Now: "same amount of data" - perhaps that refers to output? What I meant is, if you run the query on "this" server "here", but the data is in a table on a remote server (accessed through dblink), you need to read the entire table twice (unless it's all cached after the first read, which may or may not be the case).

Comment: Then - I don't think UNPIVOT needs a temp table. It should be able to produce both rows of output from reading and processing one row of input, all at once. Then it's done with that input row, it doesn't need to revisit it later.